# Python double list compression with a third unrelated item

Tags: python, list

I have a nested list comprehension like this:

```
self.Item = [[Object(x, y) for y in range(3)] for x in range(3)]
```

Now I need to do the same thing, but Object has a third parameter: Index (which is just an int 0-9, consecutively).

```
self.Item = [[Object(x, y, index) for y in range(3)] for x in range(3)]
```

The solutions I found used enumerated(), but I found it hard to implement with two lists.

Comment: Enumerate both and multiply together?

Comment: I tired that, but it gives a weird pattern of things with the same index because of zero product property

Comment: You can choose the starting number to [**`enumerate`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) from.

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
z=0 
L = []
for x in range(3):
    for y in range(3):
        L.append(Object(x,y,z))
        z+=1
```

Personally, for use-cases like this, I tend to find [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) very helpful to use instead of nested for loops. You can add more iters to your `itertools.product` without worrying about nightmarishly nested loops.

```
import itertools

L=[]
z=0 

for X in itertools.product(range(3),range(3)):
    
    L.append(Object(X[0],X[1],z))
    z+=1
```

I just wouldn't do what you have above. Split out your code and make it 100X more readable and debuggable in the future. Code like this feels fun and pythonic but is a terrible idea.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense thanks! List comprehension is just hard to resist

Answer (score 2):

Using an infinite iterator:

```
from itertools import count
index = count()
self.Item = [[Object(x, y, next(index)) for y in range(3)] for x in range(3)]
```